# NextJS 13 with axios throw Error connection ECONNREFUSED ::1:3000

Tags: node.js, next.js, axios

I am using Axios and after the project was ready, I had the shocking result that throws an error of connection. But cannot understand why... In development it works perfectly. I read before that I need to downgrade to node 16... But that's not a good option for me because I have other collaborations on projects that uses node 18...

I tried to replace also with the IPV4 ip, but same result...

```
export const API_Endpoint = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000/api/'
});


//get all the quotes
export const getAllQuotes = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await API_Endpoint.get('get-quotes');
        return response.data;
        
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('', error);        
    }
};
```

[image]

Comment: Next.js [recommends `swr`](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/client-side#client-side-data-fetching-with-swr) for data fetching. You should probably use it